# Strange format of a table in a txt file

Tags: powershell

In a powershell script, I am creating a txt file:

```
#Create a logfile
$logfile = "E:\scripts\Password expiration\PasswordExpiryLog.txt"

#Initialize the log file with the date
$date = Get-Date -Format "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"
$message= "********************"  + $date  + "********************"
Add-Content $logfile $message
```

After that, I do some other things to get some info. When I try to send that info into the TXT file, formatting the info as a table, it writes the information in a way that the information is not in columns, missing the break of line. I mean, if I press enter where the next line should start, it is written in a column.

```
$Expired | FORMAT-TABLE @{Name='UserPrincipalName';Expression={"$($_.UserPrincipalName)"};align ='left'}, @{Name='rapasswordexpiring';Expression={"$($_.rapasswordexpiring)"};align ='center'}, @{Name='PasswordLastSet';Expression={"$($_.PasswordLastSet)"};align ='left'} -AutoSize | Out-File -Append 'E:\scripts\Password expiration\PasswordExpiryLog.txt'
```

I have also realized, while writing this message, that between the characters there is always a space

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsDq0.png)

[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DdqJ.png)

If I instead of out-file to the same logfile I use a new txt file, the information is written correctly.

```
$Expired | FORMAT-TABLE @{Name='UserPrincipalName';Expression={"$($_.UserPrincipalName)"};align ='left'}, @{Name='rapasswordexpiring';Expression={"$($_.rapasswordexpiring)"};align ='center'}, @{Name='PasswordLastSet';Expression={"$($_.PasswordLastSet)"};align ='left'} -AutoSize | Out-File -Append 'E:\scripts\Password expiration\table.txt'
```

[Correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4HUp.png)

However, I cannot get here the date and time.

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong or how to improve the output? I would be able to use cvs or html file if would be better.

Comment: To add to JosefZ's helpful answer: Note that the problem of differing default character encodings only arises in the legacy, ships-with-Windows _Windows PowerShell_ edition (`powershell.exe`, whose latest and final version is 5.1), whereas the install-on-demand, cross-platform [_PowerShell (Core)_](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) edition (`pwsh`, versions 6 and above) now consistently defaults to (BOM-less) UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different default encoding:

- [`Add-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content?view=powershell-5.1):

> `-Encoding` Specifies the type of encoding for the target file. The
> **default value is `Default`**.
>
> `Default` Uses the encoding that corresponds to the system's active
> code page (usually `ANSI`).

- [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Out-File?view=powershell-5.1#parameters)

> `-Encoding` Specifies the type of encoding for the target file. The
> **default value is `unicode`**.
>
> `unicode` Uses `UTF-16` with the little-endian byte order.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much. I was convinced that it would be something like that but I couldn't find what I needed. I have added the "-encoding bigendianunicode" and now it seems to work. Thank you very much once again.

Comment: I'd follow [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/) (force `UTF8` instead of `BigEndianUnicode`, see also the [helpful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71253573/strange-format-of-a-table-in-a-txt-file/71254347?noredirect=1#comment125954669_71253573) by @mklement0.